# Update 3rd table column based on other 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables with below structure:

```
 ______________
| ContractInfo |
|--------------|
| ContractId   |
| QuotationId  |
| SupplierId   |
|______________|

 ____________
| Quotation  |
|------------|
| Id         |
| ContractId |
|____________|

 ___________________________________
| QuotationInfo                     |
|-----------------------------------|
| QuotationId (References Quotation)|
| SupplierId                        |
|___________________________________|
```

I would like to copy the values of `SupplierId` from `ContractInfo` to `SupplierId`column of `QuotationInfo` if `QuotationId` of `QuotationInfo` equals to Id of `Quotation` and `ContractId` of `ContractInfo` is equal to `ContractId` of `Quotation`.

For example,

Suppose `ContractInfo` has below data:

```
ContractId  QuotationId SupplierId  
C-1         Q-1         S-1
C-2         Q-2         S-2
```

Suppose `Quotation` has below data:

```
Id   ContractId
Q-1  C-1
Q-2  C-2
```

and suppose `QuotationInfo` has below data:

```
QuotationId SupplierId
Q-1         NULL
Q-2         NULL
```

After the update query, the QuotationInfo SupplierId column should be populated as below:

```
QuotationId SupplierId
Q-1         S-1
Q-2         S-2
```

Couldn't really understand how I can achieve that.
Looking for help in achieving what I have described. If not the complete solution, some hints would be helpful too.

Comment: The `Quotation` table implements a many-to-many relation. What would you do if the contract had multiple quotations?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use merge

```
merge into QuotationInfo qf
using
(
select cf.SupplierId,cf.QuotationId  from 
ContractInfo cf 
inner join
Quotation Q 
on
cf.ContractId=Q.contractid
and 
cf.QuotationId  =q.id                   
)t 
on
(t.QuotationId=qf.QuotationId )
when matched then
update set qf.SupplierId=t.SupplierId
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `QuotationId` is unique to `ContractInfo`, you can use a subquery to copy `SupplierId` from `ContractInfo` to `QuotationInfo`

```
update QuotationInfo t1
set SupplierId = (select SupplierId
    from ContractInfo t2
    where t2.QuotationId = t1.QuotationId)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE QuotationInfo qi
SET qi.SupplierId = ci.SupplierId
FROM QuotationInfo qi
INNER JOIN Quotation q ON q.Id = qi.QuotationId
INNER JOIN ContractInfo ci ON ci.ContractId = q.ContractId
```